# SELECT ... AS ... with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to make a query like this with rails?

```
SELECT items.*, (select count(*) from ads where item_id = items.id) as adscount WHERE 1
```

And then access this field like so?

```
@item.adscount
```

For example for each item there is a hundred ads or so.
And in items index view I need to show how many ads each item has.

For now I only found out how to make a unique query for every item, for example:

```
select count(*) from ads where item_id = 1
select count(*) from ads where item_id = 2
select count(*) from ads where item_id = 3
etc
```

Edit:

Made a counter cache column.

That gave me huge performance improvement.

Comment: I'm 99.99% sure that Item.ads.count will generate query you need. (where Ad belongs_to Item and Item has_many Ads

Comment: Actually you just need the `has_many :ads` part in your `item.rb` model and `@item.ads.count` will do just that.  (You only need the `belongs_to :item` if you plan on accessing the item through the ad.)

Comment: Yeah, @item.ads.count will count ads for every item. But if I have 100 items - that's 100 queries, which is not the best thing. I almost feel like I should make a counter cache column for Items table.

Comment: Wouldn't you still need 100 queries to create the data in that column?

Comment: Yeah, it will be 100 queries. But sometimes you want little fast queries (wish you can cache) instead of one huge query. And yeah, counter cache should be easier to implement and faster (probably)

Comment: Devin Stewart - true, but then user won't see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Rails `Counter Cache` http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Then you will be able to use it like `@item.ads.count` and this will not produce any database queries.
And in addition (if you really want to use it your way) you can create a model method

```
def adscount
  self.ads.count
end
```

Comment: idk but most people said counter cache is not reliable better to use calculate/sql solution instead

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use [Scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes). You can either have it be a special query, like

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_adscount, select("items.*, (select count(*) from ads where item_id = items.id) as adscount")
end
```

Then in the controller, or where ever you query from, you can use it like so:

```
@items = Item.with_adscount
@items.each do |item|
  item.adscount
end
```

Or, you can put it as the [default scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#applying-a-default-scope) using:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope select("items.*, (select count(*) from ads where item_id = items.id) as adscount")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it at the controller like this

```
a = MyModel.find_by_sql('SELECT *, (select count(*) from table) as adscount FROM table').first
a.adscount #total
a.column1 #value of a column
a.column2 #value of another column
```